# JavaFX FileChooser Filefilter not returning extension

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

In my project I use JavaFX FileChooser to let the user save files. I noticed a bug, where a file with a specified file filter would always save as a .txt on Linux systems. From another stackoverflow thread I leaned that unlike Windows, on Linux the `fileChooser.showSaveDialog();` returns a file without the chosen file extension. I am confident, that this irregular implementation has a very obvious cause that I am not understanding. But still I am not sure how to adapt this for my needs.

I am aware that there are some other solved threads about a similar topic, but all the solutions are based on extracting the extension from the returned file, where in my case there is no extension returned by showSaveDialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example that adds an extension if the user didn't type one using their selected filter:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Save to file.");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter xmlfilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("XML", "*.xml");
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter mffilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("mf", "*.mf");
            fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(xmlfilter,mffilter);
            fc.setSelectedExtensionFilter(xmlfilter);
            File f = fc.showSaveDialog(primaryStage.getOwner());
            System.out.println("f = " + f);
            if(null == f) {
                return;
            }
            final String selected_description = fc.getSelectedExtensionFilter().getDescription();
            System.out.println("selected_description = " + selected_description);          
            if(selected_description.equals(xmlfilter.getDescription()) && !f.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
                f = new File(f.getParent(),f.getName()+".xml"); 
            } else if(selected_description.equals(mffilter.getDescription()) && !f.getName().endsWith(".mf")) {
                f = new File(f.getParent(),f.getName()+".mf");
            }
            System.out.println("f = " + f);
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Example");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I tested it on linux and never saw it add a .txt. A given extension filter might have multiple extensions so you will have to choose one to add arbitrarily.

Comment: Apologies. I should have discovered that getSelectedExtensionFilter() on my own. I was just directly returning the file from showSaveDialog() without thinking about using the object to gather more information. But although this is an appropriate answer to my question, the problem of saving files still remains: How to handle duplicate extensions; How to prompt in case of overriding. I think I was just expecting a simple solution already given by FileChooser that I was missing. But then again, an answer was never simple. But anyway, thank you for the answer :)