# JavaFX FileChooser behavior inconsistent on combined extensions

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, filechooser

I'm trying to use the JavaFX [FileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) to save files with combined extensions, e.g., `.tar.gz` with an extension filter `*.tar.gz`. However, the behavior of the file chooser for adding the file extension to the file name is different whether the (same) file name is typed by a user or set using `setInitialFileName`. It's also very puzzling. The minimal working example is below. The following behavior can be observed (where "none" means click Save directly and "retype" means delete and retype the last character of the file name in the file chooser before saving). This is on Windows.

```
| initial     | shows up as | action | final name  |
|-------------|-------------|--------|-------------|
| test.tar    | test        | none   | test.tar    |
| test.tar    | test        | retype | test.tar.gz |
| test        | test.tar    | none   | test.tar.gz |
| test        | test.tar    | retype | test.tar    |
| test.tar.gz | test.tar    | none   | test.tar.gz |
| test.tar.gz | test.tar    | retype | test.tar    |
```

Is there a logic to this behavior?

**Question:** How can I configure the FileChooser so that the `File` returned by `showSaveDialog` has the combined extension (e.g., `.tar.gz`) independently of whether the content of the input textfield has neither, one, or both extensions?

My goal is to provide a consistent and predictable file name given the selected extension filter, and to the extent possible avoid changing the file name after the chooser is closed (because this requires another file existence check). The `FileChooser` documentation has nothing about this, and the [closest I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757375/javafx-filechooser-filefilter-not-returning-extension) does not illuminate this functionality.

#### Update:

On Windows, enabling "View Extension" in the file explorer eliminates the discrepancy caused by retyping the file name, but not the widget's inability to handle the partial extension. For example, entering `test.tar` as file name shows up as `test.tar` (not `test.tar.gz`), and likewise saving saves as `test.tar` *even if the selected extension filter is limited to `*.tar.gz`*.

#### Minimal Working Example

```
public final class Test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button chooser = new Button("Chooser");
        chooser.setOnAction(e-> showChooser(stage));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(chooser));
        stage.show();
    }   

    static void showChooser(Stage stage) {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new ExtensionFilter("zipped tar files", "*.tar.gz"));
        chooser.setInitialFileName("test.tar"); // or "test" or "test.tar.gz"
        System.out.println(chooser.showSaveDialog(stage));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is not defined by JavaFX, but rather by the “Hide File Extensions” option of the Windows desktop/shell.  I observed similar behavior in Notepad.  Unchecking that option causes the program to exhibit much more predictable behavior.  So I’m inclined to say that the answer is, it’s under the end user’s control.

Comment: I don’t think the extension filter will automatically append an extension to the file name, while Hide File Extensions is not active.  Indeed, it appears the question to which you’ve linked has an answer that addresses that.  I think if Windows is not hiding file extensions, what you type is what you get, every time.  Exactly what happens when Windows *is* hiding file extensions is something I’ve never been able to precisely define.  I suspect it was never designed to deal with extensions containing more than one period.